# What to name a factory that accepts third party library interface?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, factory, software-design

I used inversify to handle my dependency injection which is great but I'm having trouble coming up with a name for the method / class that will wrap this classes so I can get their instance.

These are my codes so far:

controller.interface.ts

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

export interface Controller {
  handler: (
    req: Request<any, any, any, any>,
    res: Response<any>,
    next: NextFunction
  ) => Promise<void>;
}
```

create-item.controller.ts

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { injectable } from 'inversify';

import { Item } from 'src/models';
import { ItemsRepository } from 'src/repositories';

import { Controller } from 'libs/interfaces';

@injectable()
export class CreateItemController implements Controller {
  constructor(private itemsRepository: ItemsRepository) {}

  async handler(req: Request<unknown, unknown, Item, unknown>, res: Response) {
    await this.itemsRepository.put(req.body);

    res.status(204).send();
  }
}
```

inversify.config.ts

```
import { Container } from 'inversify';

import {
  CreateItemController,
  FindItemsController,
  GetItemController,
} from 'src/controllers/items';
import { ItemsRepository } from 'src/repositories';

const container = new Container();
container.bind(ItemsRepository).toSelf();
container.bind(FindItemsController).toSelf();
container.bind(CreateItemController).toSelf();
container.bind(GetItemController).toSelf();

export { container };
```

and then I created a factory that is used this way:

routes.ts

```
import {
  CreateItemController,
  FindItemsController,
  GetItemController,
} from 'src/controllers/items';
import { ControllerFactory } from 'libs/factories';
import { container } from './config/inversify.config';

export const attachPrivateRoutes = (app: any): void => {
  const controllerFactory = new ControllerFactory(container);
  app.get('/items', controllerFactory.getHandler(FindItemsController));
  app.get('/items/:sku', controllerFactory.getHandler(GetItemController));
  app.post('/items', controllerFactory.getHandler(CreateItemController));
};
```

---

This the part I having trouble with:

controller.factory.ts

```
import { Container, interfaces } from 'inversify';

import catchErrors from 'libs/errors/catch-errors';
import { Controller } from 'libs/interfaces';

export class ControllerFactory {
  container: Container;

  constructor(container: Container) {
    this.container = container;
  }

  getHandler(
    controller: interfaces.ServiceIdentifier<Controller>
  ): Controller['handler'] {
    const instance = this.container.get<Controller>(controller);
    return catchErrors(instance.handler.bind(instance));
  }
}
```

My dilemma is that it relies on the interfaces set by inversify, what if in the future I decide to not use inversify.

Should I name this class InversifyControllerFactory?
Should I make a BaseControllerFactory?
Is this even a proper factory? or should it have a different name?

Comment: If there are other things that seems weird or wrong in my code, let me know :)

Comment: `ControllerFactory` sounds pretty good to me. You don't want `Inversify` in the name because whatever calls this factory doesn't need to know that.